# Error while using Emma in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, runtime-error, emma

I am trying to use Emma in Eclipse for instrumenting Android. The versions used goes like:

```
Eclipse: 3.7.2
Android: 4.0.3 (ICS)
Emma: 2.1.4 (taken from the eclemma.org)
```

Unzipped the emma zip file into the dropins directory of eclipse and restarted. After restart, I could see the coverage icon.
I then tried to launch my existing unit testcase (that uses JUnit3) by right-clicking on the unit test method -> Coverage as -> JUnit test
This would not work (since the testcase should be run as Android JUnit test), so I added the android.jar to the classpath and ran the test again. But a RuntimeException is thrown

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at junit.framework.Assert.<init>(Assert.java:4)
at junit.framework.TestCase.<init>(TestCase.java:7)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader$1.<init>(JUnit3TestLoader.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.warning(JUnit3TestLoader.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.createTest(JUnit3TestLoader.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.getTest(JUnit3TestLoader.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit3TestLoader.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Has anyone been able to get emma running in eclipse for Android?
I was able to get emma work outside eclipse (from command-line)

Comment: Yes I use ECLEmma with Robolectric, it's an eclipse plugin: http://www.eclemma.org/ . The 'Stub' exception is because you aren't using Robolectric http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/